# Equivalence between definitions of Tensor Products (Of Vector Spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I've read the definitions in the book of Kostrikin and in the book of Sterling Berberian. The book of Berberian gives a definition for the product of two spacees, Kostrikin gives it more generally.
The Berberian definition is:

> $V\otimes W=\mathcal{L}(V^*,W)$, that is, the linear mappings from the dual of $V$ to $W$. Then he defines $v\otimes w\in V\otimes W$ such that for $f\in V^*$, $(v\otimes w)(f)=f(v)w$.

Let's denote this definition with $\otimes_1$.

The Kostrikin construction is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329735/kostrikins-definition-of-tensor-product), let's denote it with $\otimes_2$

The question is: Is there any way to extend the Berberian definition to $n$ spaces in a way that it coincides with Kostrikin's?

Comment: One could always define $U \otimes_1 V \otimes_1 W := U \otimes_1 (V \otimes_1 W)$. With finite dimensional spaces, the two definitions of the tensor product are certainly isomorphic.

Comment: So an inductive definition coincides with the other? Oh, thanks.

Comment: Up to an isomorphism of vector spaces, certainly. However, taking the dual of infinite dimensional spaces can be problematic.